# How to read/input lines from a text file into a Google search automation script?

Tags: python, loops

My question was a 2 part question which caused confusion. I was attempting to write script to pull search terms from a txt file and search each term individually. The best answer guided me in the right direction and pointed out that I had an error in the code that searched for all the terms in the txt file at once.

I'm trying to create a short Google search automation script using Selenium in Python. First, I need to get the read txt loop created first. Here's my script at the moment:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

Comment: I've removed the Selenium related tags since Selenium isn't required to repro the issue. Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: The intention is for every question anyone asks to follow these rules, including this one. I've fixed it for you this time as an example.

Comment: You never added what the actual issue is with your current code... is it throwing an error or not working as intended? If it's throwing an error, post the entire error message and clearly indicate which line of code the error is being thrown on. If it's not working as intended, clearly explain what the code is intended to do and what it's currently doing. That includes editing this question and adding these details.

Comment: My question was answered. Now I need to figure out how to loop the script to search for each term in my list. I assume I should create another question.

Comment: Whether or not your question was already answered doesn't mean that you shouldn't follow the rules for this question. The intent of SO is to build a repository of good questions and answers. This question doesn't currently rate as a good question yet. It still needs the error message, etc. that I described above.

Comment: Two-part questions are not allowed because they DO cause confusion and readers may be unsure which question to answer or only answer one of the two, etc. causing even more confusion. I would suggest you take a longer look at [ask] and fully understand the rules before asking another question.

Comment: ...and finally, Yes... each question you ask should be a separate question on the site.

Comment: would it be best to delete this question?

Comment: It's not clear at this point from the simple code loop and limited info you've provided so far. I would say this is very likely a duplicate of many other questions that already exist on this site. So, unless you've got some new, interesting detail that makes this question unique, I would say deleting it would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go through the test file and send each line to the search input tag

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
        #identify search box
        m = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        #enter search text
        m.send_keys(line)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        #perform Google search with Keys.ENTER
        m.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: A little consolidation and one wrong variable. Thanks for your help. I will look to see how to loop so it will go through every item within the list as it is just one text file.

Comment: if line in lst to check if it's valid or something